# Second display dected but not shown. Previous threads haven't helped

Tags: display

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my desktop. Everything was going well then suddenly only one of my displays are showing. When I power up the computer, both displays show up, in the log in screen both displays are showing up. Once I start my session, then only one display shows up. If I switch one screen off, the other one turns on. If I unplug one of the screens, then the remaining display still shows but the tool bar on the side is gone.  This is the output from xrandr:
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5040 x 1050, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.95*+  59.88
   1600x1024     60.17
   1400x1050     74.76    70.00    59.98
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x960      60.00
   1360x768      59.80    59.96
   1152x864      75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00
   1024x768      60.04    75.03    70.07    60.00
   960x720       75.00    60.00
   928x696       75.00    60.05
   896x672       75.05    60.01
   960x600       60.00
   832x624       74.55
   960x540       59.99
   800x600       75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25
   840x525       74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88
   800x512       60.17
   700x525       74.76    70.06    59.98
   640x512       75.02    60.02
   720x450       59.89
   640x480       60.00    75.00    72.81    75.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
   680x384       59.80    59.96
   576x432       75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06
   512x384       75.03    70.07    60.00
   416x312       74.66
   400x300       72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34
   320x240       72.81    75.00    60.05
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +
   1600x900      60.00
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      75.03    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   640x480       75.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 1680x1050+1680+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.95*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      75.03    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   640x480       75.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected 1680x1050+3360+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.95*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      75.03    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   640x480       75.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08

Any clues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Umm strange, I see no connected monitors??  Please boot your system with 1 monitor connected, give the command: `xrandr | grep '^[A-Z]' >monitor1.out 2>&1`. Shutdown your system, connect the second monitor, boot and give the command: `xrandr | grep '^[A-Z]' >monitor2.out 2>&1`. Give me the output of: `cat monitor1.out; cat monitor2.out`.

Comment: You could troubleshoot by yourself first, after reading: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I actually played around with the display settings, deleting some extra displays that ubuntu was detecting, and something I did fixed it eventually...for now anyway. Hopefully it will be good for now on!